# Why does this not violate Gauss' laws?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, gauss-law

Assuming a closed surface like the one I have (professionally) drawn in green, would this not violate both Gauss' laws? 
[image]
Both electric and magnetic fluxes would be nonzero in vacuum. I know the average flux would be zero because it's a travelling wave, but Gauss' law should always hold (and NOT only in electrostatics, as some people think).

Obviously Gauss' law isn't wrong, so what is the problem with what I have drawn?

Comment: I don't see how that's a closed surface, though.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary closed surface tangent to the horizontal axis

Comment: It is not a closed surface.  A closed surface would define an interior and an exterior region, and the only way from one to the other would be to go through the surface.  As drawn your green area is an open surface so Gauss's law does not apply.

Comment: It's not supposed to be flat, the black line is just the outline of the closed surface, not the boundary of a flat disk. Just like you draw a circle to represent a sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your picture, the field is translationally invariant in both dimensions orthogonal to the direction of propagation. This means that along any given slice, there is a uniform electric field, and all the field lines that go into your closed surface go straight through in a straight line and exit out of the other side. Thus, Gauss's law is not broken at all.

Similarly, Mark H's claims that Gauss's law gets broken at the edge of a laser beam which has a finite extent are incorrect: at the edges of the beam (along $x$, say, with the beam propagating along $z$) the field component $E_x$ will decrease with $x$, but at this point the scalar-optics approximation breaks down, and the picture you drew is no longer accurate. There the field has a longitudinal component $E_z(x,z)$, which makes the divergence cancel out exactly.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I wish I could accept all three, since all three offered some insight into it. Sean gave the initial answer, saying that I wasn't considering all directions of propagation, Mark pointed out that his argument wasn't complete because of lasers, and Emilio gave the final answer to that. Sean also edited his answer  to include lasers. I find it a rather beautiful example of how to do science.

But I have to choose an answer, so I will choose Emilio's, since it is more accessible to someone that doesn't have the necessary mathematical background.

Answer (score 4):

The fields are not confined to that line. They fill space in both directions transverse to it, uniformly. Mathematically, those fields are given by the real parts of:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}, t) & = \mathbf{E}_0 \operatorname{e}^{-i\omega t + i \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}} \\
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}, t) & = \frac{\mathbf{E}_0 \times \mathbf{k}}{\omega} \operatorname{e}^{-i\omega t + i \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}.
\end{align}
Note that $\mathbf{E}_0 \cdot \mathbf{k} = 0$. Take the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of both of those expressions, and you'll find that they are identically zero everywhere, satisfying Gauss's law.

Looking only at the plane waves is deceptively powerful because Fourier analysis teaches us that we can express any wave as a sum of Fourier components. In other words, a general classical electromagnetic field in free space can be written as:
$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) = \int \mathbf{E}_0(\mathbf{k}) \operatorname{e}^{-i\omega t + i \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}} \operatorname{d}^3k$$
and, as long as $\mathbf{E}_0(\mathbf{k}) \cdot \mathbf{k} = 0$ for all wave vectors $\mathbf{k}$, the resulting wave will satisfy Gauss's law. Say, for example, we wanted to have a wave that is concentrated at $\mathbf{k} = k_0 \hat{z}$ with a width $\sigma$ in all three directions, then we could write:
$$|\mathbf{E}_0(\mathbf{k})| \propto \operatorname{e}^{- (\mathbf{k} - k_0\hat{z})^2 / (2\sigma^2)}.$$
That satisfies the magnitude, but getting the direction of $\mathbf{E}_0$ to be perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$ everywhere is an interesting exercise in polar coordinates, and computing the resulting directions the electric field points in real space is another exercise altogether. As Emilio Pisanty pointed out, the end result will be that the net electric field will have a $z$ component from those Fourier waves that are not on the $k_z$ axis.

Comment: Oh I see! So is this usual picture of an EM wave confined to a single line physically impossible because it would violate Gauss' laws?

Comment: Yes, it's only drawn that way for clarity/simplicity.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I wish I could accept all three, since all three offered some insight into it. Sean gave the initial answer, saying that I wasn't considering all directions of propagation, Mark pointed out that his argument wasn't complete because of lasers, and Emilio gave the final answer to that. Sean also edited his answer  to include lasers. I find it a rather beautiful example of how to do science.

But I have to choose an answer, so I will choose Emilio's, since it is more accessible to someone that doesn't have the necessary mathematical background.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in response to Sean's answer.

<s>Not all electromagnetic waves are plane waves that extend uniformly in all directions perpendicular to the direction of travel. The fields that form a laser beam quickly taper off in the transverse directions, leading to a non-zero flux through a closed Gaussian surface traveling along with the wave.</s>

The preceding paragraph is wrong. The problem with a reference frame that catches up to a beam of light is that the fields become static. According to Maxwell's equations, static electric and magnetic fields are curl free. One consequence of this is that the fields are conservative: taking a line integral of the field over a closed loop must return zero. And yet, if you imagine a rectangle with its top and bottom parallel to the direction of travel and sides parallel to the electric field, with one side on a node and the other in the peak field, the integral around this loop is non-zero. The top and bottom contribute nothing due to being perpendicular to the electric field, the side in the null region contributes nothing, and the side in the peak field region has a non-zero contribution to the integral.

I'll leave this up since the history is interesting.

What you've hit upon is one of Einstein's reasons for concluding that there is no such thing as a reference frame that moves at the speed of light. If an observer could catch up to a beam of light and look at the fields, he would see a **static** field in a vacuum with non-zero <del>divergence</del> **curl**. Since such a thing is impossible according to Maxwell's equations, it must be impossible to catch up to a beam of light, and light travels at the same speed in all reference frames. This is why the speed of light derived from Maxwell's equations does not mention any particular frame of reference. From this beginning, Einstein worked out Special Relativity.

Comment: Interesting. But why is this not a problem if the wave travels at the speed of light? The fields are still there

Comment: @PatoRaimundo The fields are there, but relativity means it is impossible to place a Gaussian surface at a stationary point on the wave. No matter how fast the surface is moving through any given coordinate system, the light wave is moving away from that surface at the speed of light. The wave is not stationary in any coordinate system. Spacetime itself prevents you from observing an electromagnetic field with non-zero divergence.

Comment: But if you just put the surface along the wave and take a "snapshot", or calculate the divergence at that point in space at that moment in time, won't it be equally valid? Why do you need the surface and the fields to be in the same frame of reference?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo You're right. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Wait, so are you saying that Gauss' law IS violated in lasers?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo No. It's been a long time since I studied electromagnetic theory and I've forgotten some details of the various approximations to make laser wavefront propagation solvable. Gauss' law is not violated anywhere.

Comment: Then I don't understand what makes my initial picture invalid. Is it too much of an idealization?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo Your picture is fine. I was wrong about Gauss' law. See Emilio Pisanty's answer.

Comment: @PatoRaimundo And now I see Sean has updated his answer in response as well. He is also correct.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I wish I could accept all three, since all three offered some insight into it. Sean gave the initial answer, saying that I wasn't considering all directions of propagation, Mark pointed out that his argument wasn't complete because of lasers, and Emilio gave the final answer to that. Sean also edited his answer  to include lasers. I find it a rather beautiful example of how to do science.

But I have to choose an answer, so I will choose Emilio's, since it is more accessible to someone that doesn't have the necessary mathematical background.